# Passport + Express4 + local strategy - req.isAuthenticated return false

Tags: angularjs, node.js, authentication, express, passport.js

After using `req.login` with passport the `req.user` is returning the object. When i want to check if the user still logged in, the req.user is empty and `req.isAuthenticated()` returns false. Working with angular $http Any thoughts? thanks.

passport.js

```
module.exports = (app) => {

// var LocalStrategy = passportLocal.Strategy;

app.use(expressSession({ secret: 'mysecret' }));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
    done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function (user, done) {
    done(null, user);
});

passport.use(
    new LocalStrategy({
        usernameField: 'email',
        passwordField: 'password'
    },
    function (email, password, done) {
            new AdminUsers({ 'email' : email })
                        .fetch()
                        .then(function(user) {
                            // if user doesn't exists
                            if (!user) return done(null, false, { message: 'User doesnt exists' });

                            // use bcrypt to encrypt password while save, and to compare.
                            bcrypt.compare(password, user.attributes.password, function (err, res) {
                          if (!res) return done(null, false, {message: 'Invalid Password'});
                        });

                      return done(null, user);
                        });
}));
}
```

login call

```
login: (req, res, next) => {
    passport.authenticate('local', (err, user, info) => {
      req.login(user, (err) => {
        if (err) {
          res.json(err);
        } 
        else {
            res.json({ 'redirect' : '/' });
        }
        return;
      });
    })(req, res, next);
}
```

And to verify

```
res.send(req.isAuthenticated() ? '1' : '0');
```

EDIT: req.session doesn't store passport session after a successful login.

Comment: Few tips: `bcrypt.compare()` is async, so you should call `done(null, user)` from inside its callback. Also, it should be `req.logIn()`, with uppercase "I", and you're not handling errors everywhere.

Comment: Thanks! i tried with upper case and lower case (in passport docs it says that they are aliases). Also the `req.logIn` works properly, once its in the success function, the `req.isAuth` is working properly. when i call it in different call, it returns false

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know they were aliases :) Still, you should probably add some error handling and fix the async calls.

Comment: Yeah, will do :) what i did at the end is handling it in front-end with angular, didn't want to do it this way, but will work for now. Thanks!